# How are features generated and used in Stanford NER

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

Take as an example two features from [NERFeatureFactory](http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/ie/NERFeatureFactory.html):

```
pw, w, c
```

and

```
pc, nc, c
```

Questions:

1. Using the first feature function we want something like pw = 'in' w = 'Berlin' c = 'LOCATION' which would presumably get a high weight whereas changing c = 'PERSON' would get a low/negative weight. The question is, how are **w** and **pw** picked? Are they hand selected, are they taken from the vicinities of labeled words in the training set, or from the set of all possible words? *Is every combination pw, w then considered?*
2. When the second feature function is used in the training phase do the matrices in the forward-backward algorithm become N^3 where N is the number of classes. Or am I missing something?

Thank you in advance :) !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Stanford NER uses a CRF sequence model.
1. pw and w are all pairs of previous and current words seen during training. 
2. during decoding, if we have the feature template pc, nc, c, then to find the best sequence, it will have to consider N^3 possible combination of classes (for each token and the surrounding tokens).  The default model uses pc, c and considers N^2 combinations.